# blast2dem pixel alignment

Tags: lastools

Is there a way for `blast2dem` to tell exact fractional coordinates (or offset) where should the pixel in the generated GeoTIFF start?

In my case I would like to generate a raster that is perfectly aligned with pixels on XYZ tile of zoom 18. For this I reprojected the cloud to EPSG:3857 and use `-step 0.59716428347` parameter to have a correct pixel size (I compute it as `6378137 * pi * 2 / 256 / (2 ^ 18)`). Now the pixels are of the correct size but are misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% answer to the question, but I was able to achieve the result with pdal and following pipeline:

```
[
  "tile_2212800_6153600.laz",
  {
    "type": "filters.delaunay"
  },
  {
    "type": "filters.faceraster",
    "resolution": 0.14929107086,
    "origin_x": 2212775.531831312,
    "origin_y": 6153562.962094157,
    "width": 10000,
    "height": 10000
  },
  {
    "type": "writers.raster",
    "filename": "outputfile2.tif"
  }
]
```